# Power loss of MOSFET

Tags: power, mosfet, switching-losses

How can I calculate the power loss of a dpak Mosfet after adding thermal vias around it?
I added a 14x7 matrix of 0.5mm THT vias with in between distance of 1.3mm to relieve the thermal stress around a Mosfet that conducts 3A of current.
according to the datasheet of the device I'm using these are the equations to calculate the power loss:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The power loss before adding the thermal vias will likely be very close to the power loss before you added them.

Comment: so the thermal vias don't help with decreasing the power loss?

Comment: Power loss is volts x amps.

Comment: @1234 right. They are to reduce the thermal resistance, so the power loss doesn't make the MOSFET too hot

Answer (score 2):

Your 2 equations tell you only how many watts of heat is generated - the first one tells it in the ON-state and the 2nd during the state transitions - that's why there's the switching frequency and state transition parameters. The equations know nothing of how and how effectively you are going to keep the MOSFET cool. The temperature rise of the silicon inside your MOSFET is the result of power dissipated in the MOSFET, and the cooling. The temperature rise does not affect the power dissipation except indirectly by changing the properties of the MOSFET. Due to the rise of the temperature, the circuit can behave differently after getting hot.

Thermal vias are one practical way to use the circuit board copper more effectively to transfer the heat into the air i.e. to use also the 2nd surface copper as a heatsink.

Thermal vias and the bigger surfaces which do the actual cooling are difficult to design. Some possibilities:

- use an existing design (including what's around the PCB) which is proven to be efficient for the same dissipation power
- use thermal simulation; it's available for advanced (high cost) board designing software as an add-on or stand alone.
- trial and error; I'm afraid everyone finally ends to this, no matter they apply the 2 previous methods, which surely can reduce the first error. Transferring the heat from surfaces to air is especially difficult to predict without making tests.

An elementary text for beginners: https://www.edn.com/pcb-design-a-close-look-at-facts-and-myths-about-thermal-vias/

The existence of the question hints that you should learn more of the power losses in switching transistors or mosfets and the basics of thermal design like

- what's thermal resistance
- cooling methods and heatsink selection

Answer (score 1):

If the improvement in power dissipation is enough to significantly reduce the MOSFET's junction temperature then there could be an improvement in power dissipation due to keeping the RDS(on) at a lower value.

In addition to knowing the initial power dissipation you would also need to know the RDS(on) temperature coefficient and the DPAK thermal resistance from junction to ambient. However since one parameter affects the other, [RDS(on) vs. junction temperature], you would need to do calculations using an iterative process. [Here is an article](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/mosfet-power-dissipation-calculation-in-highpower-supply.html) that uses a similar iterative process to determine power dissipation and if a MOSFET is suitable for a particular application.

Overall it may only be worth going through all of this if you know that you will be using the MOSFET near it's maximum operating parameters.

As a simple verification you could simply measure the DPAK's operating case temperature before and after the modifications then work the equations back to determine if there were any significant power dissipation improvements.